# Home WiFi: How to protect my PC from a nasty, tech-savvy-by-proxy roommate?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, security

(Skipping formalities, as they'll be expunged from the text, but please know I love you and greet you just the same...)

I share an appartment with two other people, one of witch (no, no, no typo) I really don't get along with.

She's been here for years, whereas I arrived a couple months ago, and she works as a data-processor with a French ISP. She doesn't know much about networks, the Internet or how a computer works, but in her work, she's in contact with a lot of techies, one of whom she somehow managed to enlist in her mission to make me leave the appartment, and, generally-speaking, make my life miserable on a daily basis.

A few days ago, she was working from home, what with the lockdown and all, and I overheard her complaining aloud on how slow our Internet was; at some point, she even said she couldn't work because she had lost connectivity via the VPN on her work laptop.

I didn't pay much attention at the time, because I was on the same home WiFi network as her (with a 100MBps fiber downlink that's both stable and fast enough for regular use) and everything was fine on my end.

Turns out she was on the phone with one of her tech friends, and she asked him to log onto our "box" (modem) admin page from his own home or office, I don't know, and "tidy things up" as far as other devices but her own were concerned.

I didn't notice anything untoward at first: no connection drops or hiccups, no slower speed, nothing.

For the past three days, however, I've noticed strange things happening on my PC that I can't help but relate to the tech's intervention on our home network: WiFi connection has become unstable, with frequent drops and slow speeds, even when no one's around; email in my Spam folders on several accounts stating that I have been observed while watching porn on my PC (not true, not true at all...), screen brightness and sound volume being changed without any intervention on my part, etc...

Just yesterday, I was researching Google on how to download an Avast standalone installer, and search results showed at least 10 pages worth of answers, but when I moved to page 2 in Google search, the number of pages was down to 2, with no answers past the usual "download the online installer and let it download the necessary files for you" stock answers.

At that moment, I really started to smell a rat. I proceeded to reinstall Windows Server 2019 on a newly-created partition with a lifelong license I got on the cheap from Microsoft a while ago, updated it to the gills, and I have decided not to use my other OS, Windows 10 Pro, for now, until I'm fully reassured on how safe it is to use this home network.

I haven't installed any new software on my PC, I use Windows Defender as AV on Server, and I'm currently using my phone's hotspot for WiFi, because I don't trust the home WiFi at the moment.

However, the downlink speed and ease-of-use make it a better option than constantly using my phone, so I'd like to switch back to the home WiFi, AFTER A THOROUGH SECURITY ASSESSMENT, and that's where you guys come in.

I'm a sysadmin by trade, but home WiFi really isn't my area of expertise. I know how to fix it when it doesn't work, but I'm in serious need of good practice tips and ideas on how to protect my PC from future intrusions, given that I'm pretty sure that's what happened.

Please note that I don't have access to the router admin page, so I can't change anything on that end. I just need to make my own PC more secure.

I've checked firewall rules and everything seems OK. Let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: Coincidence does not equal correlation and what you're experiencing is the Baader-Meinhof phenomenon.  All issues have logical explanations: (1) most have received spam emails about having your login details relating to porn, as it's due to arbitrary site data breaches _(see [Have I been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com))_; (2) WiFi drops can be a range of things - ensure your WiFi radios are set to actual channels and NOT auto _(2.4GHz: 40MHz, `1`, `6`, or `11`; 5GHz: 80MHz/160MHz, highest available, `157` (80MHz)/`114` (160MHz)  generally works the best in the US)_, etc. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _Cont'd_ (3) Some search results will list pages of returns and upon switching to the second page, only display a handful (there's likely a blog online explaining why this occurs).  (4) If you're worried about WiFi privacy on a shared radio either create separate WiFi networks for each person or use your own router downstream from the main router _(this does come with caveats, such as double NAT)_.  All in all, there's likely nothing nefarious going on and it would be recommended to simply talk to your roommate... interpersonal skills should never be undervalued.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts at assuaging my anxiety, and I'm not one to undervalue interpersonal skills, or appeals to reason, but... (and that's a big "but") This roommate of mine, for better or for worse, isn't reasonable to begin with. I won't detail here all her quirks, of which there are many, believe me, only to point that I'm the *seventh* occupant to complain to the landlord about her behavior, the previous six having fled the scene, they were so fed up with her histrionics, immaturity and general obnoxiousness, but that's a debate for another place and time. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Let summarize your very long post: You fear that something is wrong with the network but the "suspect" did not had access to your PC? If you are really afraid of that person the simplest solution would be to spend a few bucks for a cheap VPN system software/endpoint that protects all your data between your PC and the VPN endpoint. Hence the Wifi and the router can't do anything on the data even if some servers use insecure HTTP or other older protocols.

Comment: I already use a VPN for work purposes, but not all the time, and that's not the answer to my question: I suspect that the tech somehow managed to penetrate my Win10 installation while I was already connected to that AP *without the VPN running*. Using it now wouldn't solve my problem if the worm is already in the fruit. My Windows Server installation is on the same PC, only on a different partition, and is untouched, so I can work with that, but like I said in my OP, constantly using my phone as AP isn't a solution either, at least not a viable, permanent one.

Comment: If 6 of the occupants have already made complaint against her, why don't the landlord kick her out? Bdw, as Robert point, using vpn is the best bet for now, or install your own router.